# Yii2 Kartik EditableColumn ajax post URL wont change

Tags: ajax, yii2, editablegrid

This is one of the column for the gridview. This is the URL it give me `http://localhost/testing/apps/web/op/details/listing/particular`

The URL that I wanted is

`http://localhost/testing/apps/modules/op/controllers/listing/particular`

I tried

`'formOptions' => [ 'action' => ['/listing/particular'] ],`

`'formOptions' => [ 'action' => ['../listing/particular'] ],`

`'formOptions' => [ 'action' => ['apps/modules/op/controllers/listing/particular'] ],`

The problem is no matter how I modified the URL, it just keep append whatever I typed behind `http://localhost/testing/apps/web/(what i type)`
Is there anyway to remove the `web` thing?

```
[
        'class'=>'\kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute'=>'particular',
       'editableOptions' =>
        [
            'inputType' => Editable::INPUT_TEXT,
            'formOptions' => [ 'action' => ['listing/particular'] ],
            'options' => [

            ]
        ]
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [yii\helpers\Url](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-url.html) ?

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
Url::toRoute(['listing/particular'])
```